# Can't determine value of character at the end of a string

Tags: c, string

I'm new to C programming. I am trying to make a program that takes some simple input. However I found that on comparison of my input string to what the user "meant" to input, there is an additional character at the end. I thought this might be a '\0' or a '\r' but that seems not to be the case. This is my snippet of code:

```
char* getUserInput(char* command, char $MYPATH[])
{
    printf("myshell$ ");
    fgets(command, 200, stdin);
    printf("%u\n", (unsigned)strlen(command));

    if ((command[(unsigned)strlen(command) - 1] == '\0') || (command[(unsigned)strlen(command) - 1] == '\r'))
    {
        printf("bye\n");
    }

return command;
}
```

The code shows that when entering, say "exit" that 5 characters are entered. However I can't seem to figure out the identity of this last one. "Bye" never prints. Does anyone know what this mystery character could be?

Comment: The last character in a string (e.g. `command[strlen(command) - 1]`) is *never* `'\0'`. On the other hand, `command[strlen(command)]` will *always* be `'\0'`.

Comment: Btw the check `(command[(unsigned)strlen(command)] == '\0')` is meaning less `strlen()` need nul terminated string, if there is no `\0` then behavior would be undefined, and if there is nul-symbol why to check it..

Comment: You are testing for `'\r'`. But in cooked terminal mode the enter key generates a newline character, `'\n'`. Try testing for that one.

Comment: Is `$MYPATH` a valid variable name? in your function argument

Comment: Why won't you just print this character: `printf("mystery char=%02x\n", command[(unsigned)strlen(command) - 1]);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The magical 5th element most probably is a newline character: `\n`

From [`man fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) (emphasis by me):

> fgets()  reads  in  at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.  **If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.**  A '\0' is
>          stored **after** the last character in the buffer.

To prove this print out each character read by doing so:

```
char* getUserInput(char* command, char $MYPATH[])
{ 
  printf("myshell$ ");
  fgets(command, 200, stdin);
  printf("%u\n", (unsigned)strlen(command));

  {
    size_t i = 0, len = strlen(command);
    for (;i < len; ++i)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "command[%zu]='%c' (%hhd or 0x%hhx)\n", i, command[i], command[i], command[i]); 
    }
  }

  ...
```

Comment: +1 for the only correct answer posted. Funny how everyone babbling about strlen suddenly edited their answers after this one came up :)

Comment: For reference: [man `fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html)

Comment: @ElchononEdelson: Thank you. I added the link to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

assumptions

1. array indexes in c are started with 0
2. strlen returns length of string

so, if you have string `"exit"`, this will be 5 symbols in array = `e, x, i, t, \0`, strlen return 4, but you're trying to decrement it by 1, so you're checking last symbol in string, instead on NULL terminator

to check NULL terminator use `command[strlen(command)]` - this will give you `\0` always, so there is no sense in it

if you want to compare strings use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) function

UPDATE: issue with your program is because [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) appends `\n` symbol at then end of string:

> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a
>   valid character by the function and included in the string copied to
>   str.

Comment: The strlen returns 5.

Comment: _The code shows that when entering, say "exit" that 5 characters are entered._ The point is that there is no way to enter just "exit". The fifth character will always get in!

Comment: @JanHudec yes `"exit"` is consists of five chars including `\0`, And in C language `char str[4] = "exit";` is valid `\0` is not entered. Special case! `str` contains only 4 chars

Comment: Ilya, not the downvoter, but remember that `fgets` puts an extra `\n` at the end, so Jan is right

Comment: @JanHudec this is because fgets adds `\n` at the end, but for just "exit" strlen will return 4, for "exit\n" will return 5

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan `char str[4] = "exit";` means array of 4 chars, not ASCIIZ string, `strlen` can crash on such "string"

Comment: @IlyaBursov: But the newline is the main source of confusion here!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see the last char is because `strlen()` won't calculate '\0' into the string's length. So testing for '\0' wont succeed. 
for instance, `const char* a = "abc";` then `strlen(a)` will be 3. if you want to test it, you need to access it by `command[strlen(command)]`

The reason for getting `strlen` equals to 5 on "exit" is because `fgets` will append the '\n' character at the end of the input. You could test it by `command[strlen(command) -1 ] == '\n'`